# How to add multiple values for one key in a dictionary using swift

Tags: swift

I have been trying to add multiple values for one key in a dictionary.

In objective c we can write like this right:

```
NSDictionary *mapping = @{@"B": @[@"Bear", @"Buffalo"]};
```

But in Swift how can we write I am trying like this but it is not accessing:

```
var animalsDic   = ["B": "Bear","Ball",
                "C": "Cat","Camel"
                "D": "Dog",
                "E": "Emu"]
```

Can any one help me out?.

Answer (score 15):

An array can be created in swift using square brackets:

```
["Bear", "Ball"]
```

so the correct way to initialize your dictionary is:

```
var animalsDic = ["B": ["Bear","Ball"], "C": ["Cat","Camel"], "D": ["Dog"], "E": ["Emu"]]
```

Just to know what you're working with, the type of `animalsDic` is:

```
[String: [String]]
```

equivalent to:

```
Dictionary<String, Array<String>>
```

Comment: Ok thank you and i want to copy all the keys and values of my dictionary to array 

animals = [String](animalsDic.keys)

at this point i am getting an error that NSDictionary doesnot have a member named key

Comment: If you defined it as a swift dictionary, then it is `animalsDic.keys.array` - if instead it's a `NSDictionary`, then you have to use `animalsDic.allKeys`

Comment: You should post your code in order to figure out what's going on. If you think it's not directly related to this question, create a new one

Comment: i just to show B and C and D on titleforheadersection and bear Ball on row  so how can i do that ? please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add commas to separate the elements because they are used by the dictionary to separate key value pairs as well. You should be wrapping the objects in arrays like you are in Objective C. It should look like this.

```
var animalsDic = ["B": ["Bear","Ball"], "C": ["Cat","Camel"], "D": ["Dog"], "E": ["Emu"]]
```

Making animalsDic have the type `[String : [String]]`.

Comment: Ok thank you and i want to copy all the keys and values of my dictionary to array animals = [String](animalsDic.keys) at this point i am getting an error that NSDictionary doesnot have a member named key

Comment: @Santhosh I believe it should be animalsDic.keys.array