# Swift dictionary, a key with multiple values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I would like to know how I can make a key of a dictionary have multiple values according to the data that comes to it.

Attached basic example:

```
var temp = [String: String] ()

temp ["dinningRoom"] = "Table"
temp ["dinningRoom"] = "Chair"
```

In this case, I always return "Chair", the last one I add, and I need to return all the items that I am adding on the same key.

In this case, the "dinningRoom" key should have two items that are "Table" and "Chair".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple values for one key in a dictionary using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385664/how-to-add-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-a-dictionary-using-swift).

Comment: The idea in a dictionary is that the key is a 'primary key'. That is, a key can only return one value. Be it an object or array. The value type you set is `String`, not `Array`. It is like assigning a value and expecting it to retain the new and previous one.

Comment: If that would be the case how will you identify the value for a key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple values for one key in a dictionary using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385664/how-to-add-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-a-dictionary-using-swift)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Swift Tuples** for such scenarios.

```
//Define you tuple with some name and attribute type
typealias MutipleValue = (firstObject: String, secondObject: String)

var dictionary = [String: MutipleValue]()
dictionary["diningRoom"] = MutipleValue(firstObject: "Chair", secondObject: "Table")

var value = dictionary["diningRoom"]
value?.firstObject
```

Comment: And what if you have three values for the key?

Comment: Add more values in upper tuple. Swift Tuple is for multiple return type.

Comment: The point is, each tuple with a different count e.g. `(T, U)` and `(T, U, V)` is a different type in Swift. You can't store tuples with differing numbers of elements in the same dictionary.

Comment: If your count raise to N. Then for this you need Arrays not tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a dictionary whose value is an array and this can contain the data you want, for example:

```
var temp = [String: [String]]()

temp["dinningRoom"] = ["Table", "Chair", "Bottle"]
```

If you want to add a new element you can do it this way:

```
if temp["dinningRoom"] != nil {
    temp["dinningRoom"]!.append("Flower")
} else {
    temp["dinningRoom"] = ["Flower"]
}
```

Now `temp["dinningRoom"]` contains `["Table", "Chair", "Bottle", "Flower"]`

Comment: @Laffen except that he has only just tested `temp["dinningRoom"]` to make sure it is not nil.

Comment: @Laffen well, it's fixed now, so you can remove your downvote :-)

Comment: @Laffen Then whoever made the downvote can remove it.

Comment: The proper Swift 4 solution is `temp["dinningRoom", default: []].append("Flower")`, compare for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/47739419.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dictionary like this:

```
var temp = [String: Any]()

temp["dinningRoom"] = ["Table", "Chair"]
```

If you want to fetch all the elements from dinningRoom. You can use this:

```
let dinningRoomArray = temp["dinningRoom"] as? [String]

for room in dinningRoomArray{
    print(room)
}
```

It is not compiled code but I mean to say that we can use Any as value instead of String or array of String. When you cast it from Any to [String]
using as? the app can handle the nil value.

Comment: My typing mistake: user var temp = [String : Any]()

Comment: It's better to use a strong type for the values e.g. `[String]`